# Github New Project but using same existing project

Tags: github, git-bash

I completed a project. We'll call it "A". I've pushed it to the master using

```
git push origin master .........."the final A version"
```

I have a customer who wants to use "A", but with their branding. Of course these have no association.

How does one handle that? I have created a new app on Github first called "B". Is that the correct first step?

What are the steps to establish a new project on github from my local clone without fear of destroying "A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to fork your own project. In that case, you can simply make a local copy of your git repository and push it to a new github project.

1. Create a new github project, name it whatever
2. Make a copy of project A's directory on your computer, name it B.
3. In the local copy of your git project, (directory B), change git's remote URL to the new github URL.

```sh
git remote set-url <new-url>
```

where `new-url` is the new URL github tells you to push to when you created the new project.

4. Finally push your project to github `git push origin master`

Comment: I had to do it like this, but this worked. Using "'origin"

Thanks

`List your existing remotes in order to get the name 
of the remote you want to change.

git remote -v

Change your remote's URL with 
the git remote set-url command

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/............

Verify that the remote URL has changed.

git remote -v `